# Encoded password does not look like BCrypt: authentication customization against a Relational Database - Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot `2.2.5.RELEASE`.
I've researched a lot of examples on stackoverflow and other resources, but nothing helps me and I couldn't login to use `h2-console` because of warning:

```
2020-03-31 18:22:57.545  WARN 29312 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

My configuration class was like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration
        extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private final UserInfoDetailsService userInfoDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public SpringSecurityConfiguration(UserInfoDetailsService userInfoDetailsService) {
        this.userInfoDetailsService = userInfoDetailsService;
        this.dataSource = new Jdbc3PoolingDataSource();
        this.passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userInfoDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder)
            throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userInfoDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/user/**", "/h2-console/**").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .realmName("User Registration System")
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
}
```

`UserInfo` domain object was like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username")
    @NotEmpty
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean isEnabled;
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }
    public void setEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

And `UserInfoDetailsService` class was like:

```
@Service
public class UserInfoDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserInfoJpaRepository userInfoJpaRepository;

    public UserInfoDetailsService(UserInfoJpaRepository userInfoJpaRepository) {
        this.userInfoJpaRepository = userInfoJpaRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserInfo user = userInfoJpaRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                    "Opps! user not found with user-name: " + username);
        }
        return new User(
                user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                Collections.singleton(getAuthorities(user)));
    }
    private SimpleGrantedAuthority getAuthorities(UserInfo user) {
        return new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + user.getRole());
    }
}
```

Moreover, I've generated some test users:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, enabled, role) VALUES (1, 'user', 'password', true, 'USER');
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, enabled, role) VALUES (2, 'admin', 'password', true, 'ADMIN');
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, enabled, role) VALUES (3, 'users2', 'password', true, 'USER');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To identify this problem `"Encoded password does not look like BCrypt"` I setup a break point in class `org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder`. And then checked the root cause for the warning.

So, the cause of warning was because of open passwords I've inserted:

[image]

To solve it, I've encoded password and updated `users` table:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, enabled, role) VALUES (1, 'user', '$2a...', true, 'USER');
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, enabled, role) VALUES (2, 'admin', '$2a...', true, 'ADMIN');
INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, enabled, role) VALUES (3, 'users2', '$2a...', true, 'USER');
```